# How can we move Multiple Child Nodes with attribute(value) selection to the Parent Nodes also on an attribute (value) selection

Tags: xslt

Need to move the Article Nodes to the corresponding Order Lines. The Articles can be linked to the corresponding order line (DropPoint=LineNumber) or should be moved to the correct line (DropPoint<>LineNumber). When we have an article with DropPoint 30 we need to move the Article Node to the OrderLineNumber 30 node. We can have multiple Article nodes in de source XML. Source and Target structure should be equal.

Example Source XML

```
<SyncOrder>
<DataArea>
    <Order>
        <OrderHeader>
        </OrderHeader>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">30</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>30</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>50</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>30</LineNumber>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>40</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
        </OrderLine>
    </Order>
</DataArea>
</SyncOrder>
```

Example Target XML:

```
<SyncOrder>
<DataArea>
    <Order>
        <OrderHeader>
        </OrderHeader>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>30</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>40</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>50</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">10</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
        </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>30</LineNumber>
            <Article>
                <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
                <UserArea>
                    <Property>
                        <NameValue
                            name="DropPoint"
                            type="StringType">30</NameValue>
                    </Property>
                </UserArea>
            </Article>
        </OrderLine>
    </Order>
</DataArea>
</SyncOrder>
```

Below code works, but I do not want to specify fixed values. (10-20-30)
As we do not know at front how many lines and what the line numbers are.
Can we also solve this without using the fixed comparisons.
Thanks,

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//dns:Order/*:OrderLine/*:Article">
<xsl:element name="{name(.)}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//dns:Order/*:OrderLine">
 <xsl:if test="./*:LineNumber/text() = '10'">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
     <xsl:for-each select="/*:SyncOrder/*:DataArea/*:Order/*:OrderLine/*:Article">
      <xsl:if test="./*:UserArea/*:Property/*:NameValue[@name='DropPoint']/text() ='10'">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="./*:LineNumber/text() = '20'">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
     <xsl:for-each select="/*:SyncOrder/*:DataArea/*:Order/*:OrderLine/*:Article">
      <xsl:if test="./*:UserArea/*:Property/*:NameValue[@name='DropPoint']/text() ='20'">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="./*:LineNumber/text() = '30'">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
     <xsl:for-each select="/*:SyncOrder/*:DataArea/*:Order/*:OrderLine/*:Article">
      <xsl:if test="./*:UserArea/*:Property/*:NameValue[@name='DropPoint']/text() ='30'">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* " />
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has a built in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="article" match="Article" use="UserArea/Property/NameValue" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrderLine">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="LineNumber"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('article', LineNumber)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried the solution, it does not work, I need to select all nodes with *, with above solution it can not find the order line, and nothing is done. How can we store the Key, as the key is not unique. We can have several Articles with the same key. And we should compare all Order lines. Thanks,

Comment: You can see my solution working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgAEeJ